# Run sql script from another sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlproj

I want to run all scripts from specified folder. I created sql-cursor which contains script's paths.

I want to execute script and log usage of them, but how can I run sql script inside other sql script. There is ':r'  statement used in sqlproj in Visual Studio, but it doesn't work in my case, so how can I resolve it? I use SQL Server 2016.

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM ScriptsFromFolderCursor INTO @scriptName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @fullScriptPath nvarchar(1024) = @MyPath + @scriptName

        -- WHAT SHOULD BE THERE ??
        :r @fullScriptPath

        -- log usage of script
        INSERT INTO  DeployedSqlScripts([ScriptName], [Version],[DateUtc])
        VALUES (@fullScriptPath, @DbVersion, GetUtcDate())

        FETCH NEXT FROM ScriptsFromFolderCursor INTO @scriptName
    END
```

I got error:

> Error SQL72001: The included file @fullScriptPath
>   (C:\GIT\myPath\@FULLSCRIPTPATH)
>   does not exist. (54, 8)

Comment: What does `:r @fullScriptPath` do?

Comment: I've found a few descriptions of doing this in a batch file - is this OK? https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-all-Sql-in-a-Folder-4dd333f1 only thing is it won't do it in any particular order

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid :r should run sql scritps. Post which you suggest as duplicated need to mention all sql scripts from folder. I would like to automate it

Comment: Sorry - I though I retracted the duplicate after I realised you were asking for something different. Note that my suggestion `:r @fullScriptPath` is different to what you have which is `:r (SELECT @fullScriptPath)`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Your link to ScriptCenter show how to run all scripts from folder by CMD, but I want to do it by sql script.

Comment: Understood. Any particular reason why you don't want to use SQLCMD.EXE? Is it because you are automating releases?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I get error message "Error SQL72001: The included file (at)fullScriptPath (myPath....DATABASE\(at)FULLSCRIPTPATH) does not exist." when sql contains ":r (at)fullScriptPath"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I update my code and error

Comment: Clearly there is no file called `C:\GIT\myPath\@FULLSCRIPTPATH`.. anyway I'm experimenting now and I'll get back to you if I find a solution

Comment: Yes, there is no. My question is how to use value of @FULLSCRIPTPATH? There is correct file name.

Comment: This https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6dffd89-b378-4d84-822c-c9b92aaf57ce/how-to-pass-tsql-parameter-to-sqlcmd-setvar says it can't be done. You can't pass T-SQL variables into r. But it has a workaround that requires `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: Another option appears to be to generate a master script that contains explcit `r:` code to run all your scripts, and then run that master script.

Comment: Post from msdn is from 2009, maybe sb resolve this problem? :)

Comment: I don't think so. I believe SQLCMD variables are evaluated before runtime whereas T-SQL variables are evaluated at runtime. See here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1112228-392-1.aspx. There are many ways to achieve what you need to do, just not the way you want to do it. What are your constraints for this? Why can't you use a  batch file?

Comment: Oh. Here's how you do it - output to a file then run that file. Why don't you try this and post back any issues http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sqlcmd+mode/129764/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I resolve problem with OPENROWSET statement and executing its content

Comment: Now my problem is how to init working directory for publish to know path for files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what error you get, but by the looks of it you are trying to use a SQLCMD statement (`:r`)

Have you executed this script in SQLCMD Mode? [Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a scripting environment other than T-SQL, you could do this with execsql.py (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql).  The INCLUDE metacommand (http://pythonhosted.org/execsql/#include) will allow you to insert another SQL script within the running script, and the example of importing all CSV files in a directory (http://pythonhosted.org/execsql/#example13) could be easily adapted to use to include all SQL scripts in a directory.

Disclaimer: I wrote execsql.py.